# Prevent chat from scrolling while I'm mousing over controls

Tags: feature-request, chat

At the first chat meta tavern town hall thing, there were a *lot* of people in one room. This exposed a problem with the way chat works: when the messages are scrolling very fast, it's very hard indeed to reply to messages.

Is there the possiblity that chat could not scroll when there's a new message if I'm moused over `.meta` or `.action-link`?